# Keras using GPU vs CPU

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Are there any differences from the programming point of view(syntax,functions or any other ) in 'Keras with back-end as Tensorflow' while working on 'Keras GPU' and 'Keras CPU'? I meant if one program can run on a GPU enabled Keras, Will the same program run on Keras CPU(efficiency doesn't matter)?

Comment: If you write in `Keras` the answer is yes, GPU/CPU can be switched from outside of the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GPU code running on CPU? Sure, it is basic Multithreading. And you needed to avoid the race conditions anyway.
For most intents a GPU is just a giant load of realy weak CPU's, wich allows highly effective Multithreading (basically a display-high times display-width Core).

The other way (running procedural CPU code in a massively paralell GPU enviroment) is where the work lies.